# Cannot open and close a form inside of MDI form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I'm currently using an `MDI Parent Form` and inside of it I will open a `Form` by clicking in one of the items from the `ToolStripMenuItem`. I have a code which allows me to open that item only one time instead of opening multiple `Forms`.

```
frmRegUser frm = null;

private void createToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (frm == null)
    {
        frm = new frmRegUser();
        frm.MdiParent = this;
    }
    frm.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.Show();
}
```

So far so good, but then after closing the `Form` inside of the `MDI Parent Form` and try to open the same `createToolStripMenuItem` again it will displays me an error

> Cannot access a disposed object. Name of the object: 'frmRegUser'

Then I searched about it and tried to use a code inside of the `frmRegUser closing event` put this code:

```
this.Hide();
this.Parent = null;
e.Cancel = true;
```

It won't open the form again if I want too.

Do you have any ideia how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does "does not works too" mean? Of course without that `Close` event handler your `frm` gets disposed when it's closed. With that handler you avoid that by _hiding_ the form instead of _closing_. Maybe you should not set the `Parent` to null or reset it when showing again.

Comment: It solved my problem by remove the `this.Parent = null;` line @RenéVogt

Comment: frm.FormClosed += delegate { frm = null; };

Comment: I think you dont need any code at all in the closing event. Why hide a form that is closing ? why remove the parent from a form that is closing ? why setting cancel from a form that is closing ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by removing the `this.Parent = null;` from the `frmRegUser_FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure it's disposed before you initialize:

```
 if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
```

Comment: When I open the form and try to close the app in the ´X´ it will close the `Form` first